# Using .Net Library in Unity5

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I have a huge project written in c# using .Net 3.5
I need to use Unity3D for my project. I tried to import Unity into my project but I found out that it is not possible. So, now I want to import the code that I have written in C# into Unity. I created a library using the code that I already have, to import it into Unity and use it. But when I try to import it I receive the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'SpeechTools.ClsSpeechSynthesis' from assembly 'MySpeechSynthesizer,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'System.Speech, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.

I am using System.Speech in my library. It is not supported in Unity (Mono). I guess the problem is caused by this dependency.

Can anyone help me? Is there a way to write a wrapper around System.Speech.SpeechSynthesizer and use it in Unity?

I searched online and I found a lot of tutorials on writing wrappers for c++ codes but nothing for c# and .Net libraries.

Comment: In a micro services era, you can easily write a micro service and run it on .NET Framework 3.5 (why not upgrade to .NET 4.5.2 and above?), and then consume the service in a Unity application. There is really no need to merge them together and hit such nobody-care issues.

Comment: So you suggest that I write a service and use it in unity? instead of trying to write a wrapper around system.speech?

Answer (score 1):

`System.Speech` is not supported by Unity's version of Mono, so you're out of luck. You also can't just drop in the Windows version of the `System.Speech` DLL since it probably won't work with Unity's version of Mono.

You can't write a C# wrapper DLL that uses `System.Speech` either because that is essentially the same as dropping the DLL straight in. Unity's Mono will try to load it and fail.

You'll have to find either a native library that implements the feature you want and write a wrapper around that, or write an implementation entirely in C#.

You could potentially write a native wrapper (i.e. in C++) around the C# DLL. This wrapper would initialise the CLR and load the C# DLL. Then the native wrapper would be referenced in Unity. You would have to expose the entire `System.Speech` API through this native wrapper. I think this would work, but it is pretty cumbersome and would only work on Windows or platforms where .NET is available (i.e. no web player, mobile, Linux, OS X).

Comment: Is it possible to write a wrapper for system.speech and use it in unity?